# Getting rid of space after \vpageref

Tags: spacing, cross-referencing, varioref

I want to use `\vpageref` and have a comma right after it. The problem is that a space is inserted even though I defined `\reftextcurrent` to be `{}`. In the example below I could fix this by adding the `[]` to `\vpageref`, but in my book this trick somehow does not work. Is the additional space a bug? How can I fix it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varioref}
\renewcommand{\reftextcurrent}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

I have a problem with Figure~\ref{test}\vpageref[]{test}, which I cannot solve.

\begin{figure}[b]

\caption{A figure}
\label{test}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the starred version `\vpageref*` or, even better, replace the `\ref`/`\vpageref` combo with `\vref`.

(The additional space before [!] `\vpageref` is an unfortunate design decision; see section 2.2. of the `varioref` manual for details.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{varioref}

\renewcommand{\reftextcurrent}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

I have a problem with Figure~\ref{test}\vpageref*{test}, which I cannot solve.

I have a problem with Figure~\vref{test}, which I cannot solve.

\begin{figure}[b] 
\caption{A figure}
\label{test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! How silly not to take \vref in the first place. I use it at other places, but started with \ref and then thought about adding the page reference. Thanks anyway. Maybe we delete this question. Sort of embarrassing ...

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative (perhaps you've already written the book in a specific style, without knowing about `\vpageref*` or `\vref`...), you can

```
\renewcommand{\reftextcurrent}{\unskip}
```

This removes the skip that you see, and you don't have to change your code.

Answer (score 1):

I just defined me a `\aref` command which automatically adds the Prefix like Figure, ... and it adds the page reference if needed.

The code is:

```
\def\aref#1{\autoref{#1}\vpageref*{#1}}
\renewcommand{\reftextcurrent}{\unskip}
\renewcommand{\reftextbefore}{\ auf der vorherigen Seite}
\renewcommand{\reftextfacebefore}{\ auf der vorherigen Seite}
\renewcommand{\reftextafter}{\ auf der nächsten Seite}
\renewcommand{\reftextfaceafter}{\ auf der nächsten Seite}
\renewcommand{\reftextfaraway}[1]{\ auf Seite \pageref{#1}}
```

Just use it as normal `\aref{fig:Figure1}`.

Maybe it helps somebody,
Michael v.W.

Comment: Please add a full answer which shows the output of your command as well, such that other users can `copy-&-paste` the answer to test.